# Visual studio 2012 new project templates are not visible

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-templates

My visual studio 2012 is not showing templates for any language. how can I restore it or another possible solution to make it right ..

[image]

Comment: Seems that something has gone really wrong there... Reinstall!!

Comment: try reinstalling or reconfigure..

Comment: Looks like there was something wrong when installing your ide. The best option looks like `uninstalling` / `reinstalling`

Comment: I was installing wp8 sdk which was finished with an error and I have this situtation now .. :(

Comment: If there is error in installation, fix it.